# Version history maker

Tags: git, version-control, release-management

I have a few projects, managed with GIT, when I have a new release I build a typical version history file like:

```
Release 1.0.0
- Added X function
- Solved Y and Z issues
```

So far I do this by hand, reading GIT log and selecting those commit messages that are relevant to the end user, and then editing this file.

Do you know of any third party utility that makes this release history building more friendly? Maybe a tool that listens to commits and is able to select those containing a given string and output them to another file?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean always build certain files for new releases? What's the relation do you want to to do with git?

Comment: Something like having a `version_history.txt` file that is updated with some  commit messages. I think I will do a bash script to do it.

Comment: Yeah, use bash script to update `version_history.txt` file automatically during your build is ok, or you can use git per-commit hook to update  `version_history.txt` file in the same commit by checking each commit's changes. And do you still have any problems for the process or the problem has been solved?

Comment: I think so, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could write a commit hook or something, but in general, writing a changelog is a task for humans, not software, because the changelog provides a high-level view of what changed. The commit messages provide only the low-level detail.

(We thought about creating an automated changelog tool at a previous job of mine, but came to the conclusion that the info that would make a good changelog wouldn’t be available in the VCS in any automatable way.)